# Apapche conf file deny access to a specific directory for external networks apache 2.2

Tags: apache, apache-config

I have a directory

```
 /data/generated/job/
```

inside of /jobs/ i can have sub directories etc.

I also have a alias set up for

```
  /data/generated
```

My conf files looks like this.

```
 <Directory /data/generated/job>
    AllowOverride None
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 192.111 15
</Directory> 

Alias /files /data/generated
```

What im trying to accomplish is to block all access from external networks to the

```
  /data/generated/job directory so when i hit a url

  www.example.com/files/job/testing/somefile.jpg
```

This points to /data/generated/job/testing/somefile.jpg which i was blocked

I basically want everything inside of /data/generated/job/ blocked but the code above in the conf file doesnt seem to be working

Any ideas why I feel like it may be due to the symlink but i must have that symlink as it is.

I also tried

```
<Directory files/job>
   AllowOverride None
   Order Deny,Allow
   Deny from all
    Allow from 192.111 15
</Directory> 

 Alias /files /data/generated
```

and tried  as well but nothing seems to work and I can access from external network still.

Comment: I would go mod_rewrite on this one

Comment: can you give example please?

Comment: maybe this http://www.netshinesoftware.com/blog/restricting-access-to-a-url-by-ip-address-using-mod-rewrite/